# Detect front page in Drupal 6 with javascript

Tags: javascript

Using javascript in Drupal 6, is there a way to detect whether the present page is the front page? I have a custom Drupal 6 module that outputs different javascript codes based on whether the present page is front page or not. It adds a single javascript file to drupal, so I need to put the check in the javascript.

The site will be served through Varnish cache, so I don't want to add the check in PHP, though I know that would have been way easier with `drupal_is_front_page()`.

Is there any Drupal-native way to do this? jQuery based suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally Drupal adds a "**front**" class to the body element of whatever page is acting as the front page. If your theme's page.tpl.php is printing the body classes (i.e `<body class="<?php echo $classes; ?>"`), which it most likely is (it should), then your javascript can check if the body element has the "front" class.

So, assuming jQuery (because Drupal includes it) then you'd do:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('front')) { // do stuff...}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander! Got it working. I was thinking too complexly :) Thought there might be some native Drupal functions when I could simply use jQuery's selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Print the result of drupal_is_front_page() into a javascript variable, using json formatting if necessary. And just write a javascript function to check it when you need it.